# One table reference to two different tables with one foreign key, possible?

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I am not sure if this is just a lame stupid question, but then again, I just need to know how exactly database design works.

So I have this database with tables called customers, currentsurveyresults and overallsurveyresults, which show survey results the customers fill in.

```
dbo.customers
----------
customerID
customerName
surveyID

dbo.currentsurveyresults
------------------------
surveyID
questionanswer1
questionanswer2

dbo.overallsurveyresults
------------------------
surveyID
questionanswer1
questionanswer2.a
questionanswer2.b
```

To get a little bit of why I named/called the tables like this:

The overallsurveryresults table should show a more detailed table (the customer will fill in another survey after a certain date so details can be more specific later on) compared to the currentsurveyresults table (this one will be filled in earlier on).

If I understand the primary key/foreign key principle correctly, can I assign the following?:

```
customers.customerID (PK)
customers.surveyID (FK)
currentsurveyresults.surveyID(PK)
overallsurveyresults.surveyID(PK)
```

So that I can always grab the information I need from both result tables whenever I search on customers? (which means one foreign key references to two primary keys)

So the question actually is: Can a foreign key reference to multiple primary keys? If not, should I add another surveyID column which specifies each table specificly?

Comment: A foreign key references a primary key, not the other way around. Any number of foreign keys can reference a given primary key.

Comment: Thanks, edit in my question.

Comment: "Can a foreign key reference to multiple primary keys?" What does that mean? One column references two columns - how?

Comment: You have a SurveyId in the Customers Table, Can your customer only take one Survey?

Comment: The customer will make a survey of their opinion at that moment and later on they will fill in a survey with similar questions and more advanced question on that survey of their opinion at that later moment. Those tables/surveys are very similar tables/surveys but I cannot allow the second survey to overwrite the first survey results. So I think a customer takes either multiple different surveys or the same (however the latter might overwrite). As for Politank-Z: Yes I think that's not possible, so the answer might be no. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation between Customer and Survey is wrong (According to what you are trying to do).

**You said**

> The customer will make a survey of their opinion at that moment and
>   later on they will fill in a survey with similar questions and more
>   advanced question on that survey of their opinion at that later moment

You want the Customer to take more than one Survey.

Create a Survey Results table and save all results in that Table.
So you know which Customer took which Survey.

```
CUSTOMERS                        SURVEYS               Questions
---------------             |--------------------|-----------------
CustomerId (int) PK         | SurveyId (int) PK  | QuestionId (int) PK
Name (nvarchar(500))        | Name (int)         | Quesion (nvarchar(500)


SURVEY QUESTIONS (Map N-Questions against N-Survey) (Re-use Questions different Surveys)
----------------
SurveyId (FK)
QuestionId (FK)


SURVEY RESULTS  
--------------
CustomerId  (id of Customer who took Survey)
SurveyId (Id of survey taken)
SurveyDateTime (Date Survey taken)
QuestionId (FK to Question table)
Answer     (Customer Answer)
```

If you don't want to re-use the Question in Different surveys you can add it to the Question Table:

```
Questions
----------
QuestionId
Question
SurveyId (FK)
```

In this method previous survey will not get overwritten.

> So I think a customer takes either multiple different surveys or the
>   same (however the latter might overwrite)

If you want to overwrite you only have to update the `SURVEY RESULTS` Table

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I am als working with a database structure someone else has created/designed so it's a bit of hassle for me to find out what went wrong, so really thanks for the help!